# Can I use TouchID for a password in my browser?

Tags: mac, touch-id

I would like to use my touch ID to fill in my password at any website. Is there a plug-in for that or is it still impossible?

Example: Facebook asks me for a log-in on facebook.com and I want that when I lay down my finger on the touch id that it automatically fills in my password.

Do I need to dream on or is there a possibility to reach this?

Comment: Do you mean 1Password? I know they have touch bar support.

Answer (score 3):

You can [save your usernames/passwords in Safari](https://www.howtogeek.com/287884/how-to-disable-and-edit-safari%E2%80%99s-autofill-on-macos-and-ios/) and have them be filled in automatically when accessing the site. On Mojave, [this filling-in can be controlled](https://www.imore.com/safari-autofill-coming-touch-id-macos-mojave-10144) with Touch ID via the Touch ID System Settings.